# FadeIn & fadeOut happens multiple time after window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fade

I am trying to change the logo image src if not window scrollTop and backwards with a fadeIn and fadeOut effect, but even if you scroll once, fadeIn & Out happens multiple times.

I figured out with `console.log` that even if you scroll once (mousewheel or arrows), it logs many times the message (like 8,10 or 15 times). That means that the logo flashes always 10+ times before changing the src to the other image.

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '0px')).done(function () {
            $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/small-logo.png');
                console.log('bot');
            }).fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '20px 0px')).done(function () {
            $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/top-logo.png');
                console.log('top');
            }).fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-lg-3 logo no-padding-left">
      <a href="index.php">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9 no-padding-right">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               .
               .
               .
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've found and tried many solutions (like `.stop()`, if animated etc), but nothing seemed to work for me and i don't know why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem can be solved using a flag that checks if the page is scrolled to the top or not.

You just have to change your JS code like this:

```
$isScrolledToTop = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()){
        if($isScrolledToTop == false) {
            $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '0px')).done(function () {
                $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/small-logo.png');
                    console.log('bot');
                }).fadeIn();
            });
            $isScrolledToTop = true;
        } 
    } else {
        if($isScrolledToTop == true){
            $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '20px 0px')).done(function () {
                $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/small-logo.png');
                    console.log('top');
                }).fadeIn();
            });
            $isScrolledToTop = false;
        }
    }
});
```

In this way you perform image change only in two situations:

- You move away from top of the page
- You get back to top of the page

Try it, it should work!

Bye

Answer (score 1):

What if you built in a short delay to allow more scroll events to come in before you start animating like this?

```
var animationTimeout;
var isAtTop = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
         $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '0px')).done(function () {
            if (isAtTop) {
                if (animationTimeout) clearTimeout(animationTimeout);

                animationTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                        $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/small-logo.png');
                        console.log('bot');
                    }).fadeIn();
                }
                , 100);
             });
             isAtTop = false;
         }
     } else {
        $.when($('#navbar').css('padding', '20px 0px')).done(function () {
            if (!isAtTop) {
                if (animationTimeout) clearTimeout(animationTimeout);

                animationTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.logo img').fadeOut(400, function () {
                         $('.logo img').attr('src', 'images/top-logo.png');
                         console.log('top');
                    }).fadeIn();
                },
                100);
            });
            isAtTop = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and the image doesn't flash for a single scroll. But the problem now is that the image flashes whenever you scroll. Is there a way to prevent this fade if it happened already once, untill you reach top again?

Comment: I just edited the code to include a flag that might solve that problem for you? Let me know.